# Why Android Studio generate signed APK failed？

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, apk

When I import **weiboSDKCore_3.1.4.jar** and **libweibosdkcore.so**, building release .apk file doesn't work.

**weiboSDKCore_3.1.4.jar** in this path: **app/libs/**

**libweibosdkcore.so** in this path: **app/src/main/jniLibs/**

---

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaaa.bbbb"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 20161019
        versionName "2.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://mvn.leancloud.cn/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://mvn.leancloud.cn/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.bigkoo:convenientbanner:2.0.5'
    compile 'com.code19.library:library:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.zhy:okhttputils:2.6.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.pingxx:pingpp-core:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.pingxx:pingpp-alipay:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.pingxx:pingpp-wxpay:2.1.+'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.lovedise:permissiongen:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.anzewei:parallaxbacklayout:0.4'
    compile 'cn.leancloud.android:avoscloud-sdk:v3.14.5'
    compile('cn.leancloud.android:avoscloud-push:v3.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.12.0'
    compile files('libs/MiPush_SDK_Client_3_1_2.jar')
    compile files('src/main/jniLibs/BaiduLBS_Android.jar')
    compile 'cn.bingoogolapple:bga-banner:2.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.basecamp:turbolinks:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
    compile 'com.sensorsdata.analytics.android:SensorsAnalyticsSDK:latest.integration'


    compile files('libs/weiboSDKCore_3.1.4.jar')
}
```

---

**I build 3 times ,the Error Messages are:**

```
Error:  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:374)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:270)
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:  at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.<init>(ZipFile.java:393)
Error:  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.<init>(InflaterInputStream.java:187)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForJDXLRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:              java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

---

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForJDXLRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

---

```
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForJDXLRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Hope someone could teach me a thing or two? :(

Comment: search on google `OutOfMemoryError`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the reason behind your issue here. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom

Also you could find option to disable the garbage collection feature in the above link.